# Стилизация Input required и invalid

Tags: html, css, html-validation

Как сделать так, что бы до отправки формы, стиль `:invalid` не применялся и цвет оставался черным?

Пример:

```css
input {
  color: black;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" required="required" placeholder="Как вас зовут?" />
```

Все атрибуты должны присутствовать,
Есть ли возможность отменить валидацию до отправки формы, или как-то ее "обмануть" ?

Comment: А чем вам это не нравится? При пустом поле текста ведь не видно?

Comment: @korytoff проблема в том, что стиль `:invalid` применяется к `required` сразу при загрузке страницы, а не после валидации при отправке формы

Comment: так HTML5 валидация работает ПЕРЕД отправкой формы

Comment: @korytoff в том то и проблема, не могу придумать пока решения как это обойти

Comment: Не надо это обходить. Нужно просто понять что вам нужно и исходя из этого придумать реализацию. См. обновленный ответ

Comment: @korytoff мне нужно чтобы input не выглядел как ошибка, до того, как до него доберется пользователь, хочу найти решение без js

Comment: Без JavaScript никак (по крайней мере мне не известно)

Answer (score 2):

Убрать аттрибут `required`. Стиль `:invalid` применяется при ошибки валидации, а у вас у поля указан атрибут обязательного заполнения. Вот и красится красным.

### UPD

На прямой вопрос – прямой ответ. У вас не правильное понимание работы валидации в HTML5. Вам нужно по другому сформулировать вопрос, так как на текущий момент ошибки нет, работает все правильно.

Проверка полей происходит ДО отправки формы, то есть постоянно. Если вам нужна проверка формы в момент отправки, то используйте событие `onsubmit` на `JS` и ставьте свои классы для отображения ошибочных полей, как это делалось всегда.

Comment: есть ли возможно js-ом отменить валидацию при загрузке страницы? т.е. чтобы не подставлять классы, а устранить первопричину